# Bind data frame repeatedly to itself

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I want to repeat. Ie I want to do this
df<-bind_rows(df,df,df)
But ideally df would be repeated 10000 times. 
I have not found an optimal way to do this.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify=False was what I was missing.
df<-bind_rows(replicate(N,df, simplify=False)) 
Seems to be the best answer.

Comment: Ok, you can upvote Stibu's answer in the linked question, which is more comprehensive and correctly writes FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2), b=c(3, 4))
```

Then, you can use a for loop:

```
out <- df
for (i in seq_len(9999)) {
    out <- rbind(out, df)
}
```

Then, out will be df repeated 10000 times. The only downside is that it will take approximately until the heat death of the universe.
Or, a better, faster, way:

```
do.call("rbind", replicate(10000, df, simplify = FALSE))
```

Will duplicate df 10000 times, and then rbind all the results together.

Comment: I think you ought to clarify that the loop way is really, really bad. If unsure what I mean, see "Circle 2" of the R Inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Comment: Good call. Added some wit about the heat death of the universe, I hope that helps dissuade people from growing their data. That book is great, and should be automatically appended (or prepended) to every answer on questions tagged with R.